# Почему слова цыган, на цыпочках, цыпленок, цыкнуть, цыц попали в исключения?

Tags: орфография

После **ц** в корне пишется гласный **и**.

Но ведь в русском  языке буква **ц** передает твердый звук, после которого может произноситься только **[ы]**,  не **[и]**. Логично бы в корне писать ы, но русские слова *цыган, на цыпочках, цыпленок, цыкнуть, цыц*  попали в исключения, а вот по основному правилу пишутся в основном заимствования (*цитата, цивилизация*).  Почему?

Comment: Есть стандартное мнемоническое правило запоминания этого списка исключений, знакомое большинству из нас со школьной скамьи. Речь идет о формировании полной фразы из слов-исключений: «Цыган на цыпочках цыкнул цыпленку: "Цыц"!». Какой смысл перечислять эти слова в ином порядке?

Comment: Вы так учили, мы по-другому: Цыган на цыпочках подошёл к цыплёнку и цыкнул: "Цыц!" Есть и другие варианты, так что мнемотические не правила, а техники (методы) запоминания - это всего лишь  методические рекомендации.

Comment: любопытный вариант, я о нем не знал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Справка Грамоты.ру для нас расстаралась!

***...и лингвисты понимали, что изменение его написания многими было бы воспринято болезненно!***

---

[Вопрос № 269503](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=269503%09%20)

> Почему в словах цЫц, цЫган, цЫпленок пишется буква Ы, а не И? С чем
>   связанно это исключение? Слова вроде не заимствованы. Может, раньше
>   они как-то иначе произносились?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Дело в том, что слова ***цыпленок, цыпочки, цыкать, цыц*** **имеют
>   специфические междометные корни**, что оправдывает их особое
>   написание. Что касается существительного ***цыган***, то **это слово
>   осталось единственным в списке исключений, не имеющим междометного
>   корня**. Раньше таких слов было больше: ***панцырь, цырюльник, цынга,
>   цыновка*** – **написание этих слов было изменено в 1956 году** (когда
>   были приняты действующие правила русского правописания).
>
> Почему слово *цыган* осталось в списке исключений, а не стало писаться
>   через *и*, как *панцирь* и другие слова? Вероятно, это связано с тем,
>   что *цыган* – слово с богатой культурно-исторической традицией
>   (например, оно употребляется в названии поэмы А. С. Пушкина) и
>   лингвисты понимали, что изменение его написания многими было бы
>   воспринято болезненно.
>
> ---

Дополнение после полученных вопрошающих комментов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало быть, *Мцыри* - как зарегистрировано по месту обитания в 1839 году, к тому ж то дела грузинские, не нашенские ("в соответствии с традицией").

А *цыркать* - то ж [звукоподражание](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-15353.htm) такое:

> **Левша.** Это я-то? Цык! (Цыркает сквозь зубы в знак высшего презрения.) Я свою работу сделал... технически. Да...

[В 2007 году добавлено Лопатиным добавлено слово *цыркать* в исключения.](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%98%20%D0%B8%20%D0%AB%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%A6)

Об истории слова:

> При попытках сформулировать правило в конце 19 - начале 20 века
>   исследователи приводят разные перечни исключений.
>
> **Даль использует слово цыркать.**
>
> **Грот** приводит в качестве исключений *цыбик, цырюльник, цынга, цыфирь, панцырь, цыплёнок, цыган, цыкать.*
>
> **Ушаков:** *цыбик, панцырь, цынга, цыган, цыплёнок* (*цифирь, цирюльник* у него с ***И***).
>
> **В 1956 году** уменьшено число слов-исключений с Ы в корне (убраны *цыбик, цыновка, цырюльник, цынга, цыфирь, панцырь*). **Слово *цыркать* в этом списке не упоминается.**
>
> **В 1963 году комиссия Виноградова** предлагает изменить правило и после Ц
>   всегда писать И, даже в окончаниях. **Это предложение не проходит**.
>
> **В 2007 году добавлено Лопатиным добавлено слово *цыркать* в исключения**.

Comment: Так ведь я и спрашиваю, зачем они изменили написание панцырь, цырюльник, цынга, цыновка, там всё было логично, пусть бы так и оставалось.

Comment: Не так. Изменили ***всё,*** окромя междометнокорневых, лишь ***цыгану*** сделан персональный реверанс. Во имя Пушкина и гиперчувствительности отдельных лингвоособей.

Comment: А Мцыри - в честь Лермонтова? А Цыркать? Его Лопатин тоже определил  в исключения. С междометными согласна.  Мне кажется, это всё же не вся правда. Может, потому что это так называемое этимологическое написание? В русском ц твёрдое, в других языках мягкое, а русских слов с ци - цы  почти нет(только древний  союз ЦИ), их легче запомнить, тогда как иноязычных много, вот чтобы не нарушать их родное написание (там  ы нет, только и) и решили оставить ЦИ в корне, а суффикс и окончание - это уже русское словообразование, там Ы, опять-таки кроме на -ция, они же все иноязычные (классификация)

Comment: Ща дополню, ща кааак дополню ответ...

Comment: Может, тогда "изменили "всё" иностранное, чтобы не нарушать ИХ традицию, а своё русское оставили по своей традиции, но русское осталось в меньшинстве, потому и оказалось в исключениях?

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать такой вопрос. **Действительно, почему отсутствует логика в написании пяти слов?** Надо бы это исправить.

Интересно, что все попытки провести орфографическую реформу после 1956 года, всегда сводились **к нескольким темам, касающихся написания небольшого количества слов**. Казалось, что это они виноваты в том, что у нас низкая грамотность населения.

Логика – действенный и важный принцип, логичность надо  приветствовать. **Наша система правописания в целом на удивление логична,** но вот ее описание в учебниках дано не лучшим образом. **Правила без объяснений причин этих правил – вот что мешает логике,** а совсем не десяток слов, которые несложно запомнить.

Орфограмма Ы/И после Ц относится к **графическим орфограммам** (это как бы условный договор о соответствии звуков и букв,  алфавита и фонетического строя языка), а большинство наших орфограмм  **фонетические**, связанные с проверкой редуцированных гласных, измененных на стыке морфем согласных. При решении этих задач (а также при постановке знаков препинания) должна присутствовать логика.

**А графика – это нечто другое.** Во Франции, например, никто не собирается проводить реформы исторических написаний, для них это народное достояние. **Для них это история, которую нужно беречь.**

А вот у нас такой истории осталось совсем мало. Поэтому пусть она **сохранится хотя бы в написании этих пяти слов.**

Comment: Я не про "исправить", я про то, почему в 1956 году, когда все правила приводили к единообразию, чтобы не было разнобоя, решили писать ЦИ в корнях, почему бы все слова не писать с Ы, Ц ведь твёрдо произносится в русском языке?

Comment: Грамота.ру на эту тему приводит не факты, а свои фантазии, и как раз по этой теме ее тоже критикуют, особенно за пушкинских "Цаган". Даже есть такое мнение, что "цыгане" - это национальность, которая раньше писалась в паспортах, вот что трудно было бы переделать. А романтику Пушкина мало кто вообще читал. Вопрос интересный, но сложный, тут  целую статью надо писать на тему "Как это было?", наш форум особо ценной информации не прибавил. Нужен список слов, в которых Ы писалась до 1918 года, нужны протоколы заседаний, где тема обсуждалась в 1918 и 1956 году,  тогда и можно узнать "почему".